# Валидация и вывод вида в одном и том же методе

Tags: laravel

С недавних пор начал осваивать laravel. Интересует такой вопрос: можно ли сделать в laravel, например, добавление статьи и валидацию в одном и том же методе? Вижу в этом надобность, как было в codeigniter. Всех с НГ.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу комментировать, но используйте REST реализацию.
POST запросы к одному методу, а GET - к другому.
Не делайте сендвич из контроллеров. И самим же будет потом его легче читать.

```
Route::get();
Route::post();
```

Answer (score 0):

Да, если в этом есть потребность, то делаете сначала `$validator = Validate::make(...)`. Если валидатор дал ошибку (`if($validator->fails())`), бросайте исключение или ещё как обрабатывайте ошибку. Если нет, то сохраняйте статью...

Comment: if($validator->fails()) не катит так как он срабатывает даже при первой загрузке и выводит сообщения что поля пустые.

Comment: Ну, это Ваше ограничение... Добавьте условие на наличие данных в инпуте: `if(Input:all())` или то, какие поля интересны... 

Comment: ну нельзя так сделать, все перепробовал.